# Why is my lambda expression for reduce not working as expected?

Tags: python, lambda, reduce, counting

```
>>> import functools
>>> functools.reduce(lambda acc, val: acc + 1 if val == ' ' else 0, list("test test test"), 0)
0
```

I just want to count whitespaces in the text so I expected the function to return `2` (because there are two whitespaces) not `0`.

Comment: What's wrong with `"test test test".count(" ")`?

Comment: Learning python and just want to get used to python's lambdas.

Comment: It should be `else acc`.

Comment: If you're just trying to get familiar with `lambda`s then using it with `reduce` is going to blur issues... Maybe use them in a `map` or `filter` to keep it focused on the lambda and not the nuances of how `reduce` works.

Comment: @bereal, thank you very much my friend, it's working! I spent too much time and cracked my head with that ! It turns out it was so simple.

Answer (score 1):

The expression:

```
acc + 1 if val == ' ' else 0
```

is parsed as

```
(acc + 1) if val == ' ' else 0
```

so, the accumulator is reset every time it encounters anything but space. So it should be either:

```
acc + 1 if val == ' ' else acc
```

or

```
acc + (1 if val == ' ' else 0)
```

or even just:

```
acc + (val == ' ')
```

But, of course, `str.count()` is the way to go there.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to debug `lambda`s is to use a `print() or (original lambda content)`. That works because `print` always returns `None` and therefore Python will always execute the part after the `or`.

Applying that to your case:

```
import functools
functools.reduce(lambda acc, val: print(acc, val) or (acc + 1 if val == ' ' else 0), list("test test test"), 0)
```

which prints:

```
0 t
0 e
0 s
0 t
0  
1 t
0 e
0 s
0 t
0  
1 t
0 e
0 s
0 t
0
```

This gives an explanation what went wrong: You don't keep the `acc`umulator in case it's not a whitespace.

There are several ways to fix this. I'll keep the `print` for debugging reasons but if you really want to use any of those you probably should remove it.

One would be to use the fact that booleans behave like integers if used in arithmetic operations:

```
functools.reduce(lambda acc, val: print(acc, val) or (acc + (val == ' ')), list("test test test"), 0)
```

This adds 1 (`True`) to the accumulator whenever it encounters a whitespace otherwise it adds 0 (`False`).

Or the trivial solution to just keep the `acc`:

```
functools.reduce(lambda acc, val: print(acc, val) or (acc + 1 if val == ' ' else acc), list("test test test"), 0)
```

But there are much better ways to count whitespaces than using `reduce` and `lambda`. For example:

```
"test test test".count(" ")
```

which also works for your list:

```
list("test test test").count(" ")  # but that's slower
```

or:

```
from collections import Counter
cnts = Counter("test test test")  # counts all letters
cnts[" "]
```